# How to use as a default only one property from a struct?

Tags: julia, multiple-dispatch

I want to create a struct with many properties, but when applying the functions, I want it to behave like its type is one of the selected properties, for example:

```julia
mutable struct Field{T}
    field_type::T
    field_description::String
end
```

I want this struct to behave as the T type, if I assign it a String, when doing `print(Field{String}("Hello", "World"))` I want it to print `Hello`, if field type is a `Int8` I want to be able to do `Field{Int8}(1, "First term") + Field{Int8}(1,"Second term")` and get `2` and so on. Is this possible somehow?

For more context, I want this to add some metadata to the Field Type, but it has to behave as the chosen `field_type`

Answer (score 1):

You are over-complicating things. You just need to realize that `Field{String}` and `Field{Int8}` are two separate types, and treat them as such.

For example:

```
foo(f::Field{String}) = do_something()
foo(f::Field{Int8}) = do_something_else()
```

So for printing and adding, define:

```
Base.show(io::IO, f::Field{String}) = show(io, f.field_type)
Base.:+(f1::Field{Int8}, f2::Field{Int8}) = f1.field_type + f2.field_type
```

You could make it more generic by defining

```
Base.show(io::IO, f::Field{<:AbstractString}) = show(io, f.field_type)
Base.:+(f1::Field{<:Number}, f2::Field{<:Number}) = f1.field_type + f2.field_type
```

instead.

I defined `show` instead of print, since that is more convenient, but you can define any methods for any `Field{T}` that you like. Just remember that different `T` gives different types, and it's easy.

I would recomment that you create another convenience constructor:

```
Field(x::T, d) where {T} = Field{T}(x, d)
```

Now you don't need to specify `T` in the constructor call:

```
1.7.2> f1 = Field("Hello", "World"); typeof(f1)
Field{String}

1.7.2> f2 = Field(Int8(1), "World"); typeof(f2)
Field{Int8}

1.7.2> print(f1)
"Hello"
1.7.2> f2 + f2
2
```

Comment: I see, now the question is, for all the other methods I'll have to implement all the posible functions that can be applied to numbers in order to be able to treat Field{Number} as a number, right? Isn't there a way, like in OOP, to somehow "inherit" all the functions that work with Number to work with Field{Number}?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using`Base.@kwdef` or a better equivalent in the `Parameters` package.

```
Base.@kwdef struct Field{T}                          
    field::T                                             
    description::Union{String,Nothing} = nothing          
end
```

And now:

```
julia> Field(field=1)
Field{Int64}(1, nothing)
```

or:

```
using Parameters
@with_kw struct Field2{T}
    field::T
    description::Union{String,Nothing} = nothing
end
```

And now:

```
julia> Field2(field=1)
Field2{Int64}
  field: Int64 1
  description: Nothing nothing
```

However if you do not want to provide the name you can do:

```
julia> struct Field3{T}
    field::T
    description::Union{String, Nothing}
    Field3(field::T, description=nothing) where T = new{T}(field, description)
end
```

And now you can just do:

```
julia> Field3(11)
Field3{Int64}(11, nothing)
```